# Is there a way to resize non-image files for CNN similarly to image-based examples?

Tags: python, keras, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network, data-science

I am working on a research project involving brain wave data. The goal is to classify (1,0) each "image." The problem is essentially an image classification problem, where I could use a CNN, but it's not clean at all like most CNN examples online. The files that I have are tsv's (each file is an individual trial from a patient), and I have stacked them all into one pickle file with each having the participant ID and trial ID as an additional column.

I want to feed them through a CNN, but almost examples online deal with equal-sized images. My data aren't of equal size, and they aren't images. I'm wanting to use PIL to make each file the same size, but is PIL even the correct way of doing so since I don't have image files?

Comment: "PIL" stands for "Python Image Library" and so it indeed is meant to handle images only. It looks like you have to look for a non-image based solution.

Comment: so... is it images or not? also you can make a neural network that takes two kinds of inputs, e.g., images and other tabular data. `keras functional api` is a good place to start

Comment: It's not images, but I'm treating the files like images (2-dimensional arrays) since my goal is to run them through a CNN.